# Why is this the case and is it always the case for prime?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Consider the polynomial $f_n(X)=1+X+X^2+\cdots+X^{n-1}$.

I was interested in this function, and I tested out some small prime numbers -- $n=2, n=3, n=5, n=7$, to be exact.

I observed that, for $n$ that was given above, $f_n(x)\equiv1\bmod n$, for all non-negative integers less than $n$ that are not $1$, whilst $f_n(1)=0 \bmod n$.

The result generally fails for $n$ a composite number.

I was wondering if the results hold for all primes numbers; if so, why does it even hold?

This isn't a particular problem I faced; I just kind of observed and wondered why this is the case.

Comment: It is perhaps worth pointing out that the pattern repeats for $x\ge n$ and $x\le0$.

Comment: Fermat's Little Theorem is that if $p$ is prime and $p\not |\, n$ then $p|\,(n^{p-1}-1).$ It is a special case of a (later) theorem of Lagrange that if $G$ is a finite  group with $k$ members and identity $1$  then $g^k=1$ for every $g\in G.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n$ prime, by Fermat's little theorem, if $0<x<n$, then $n|x^{n-1}-1,$ so $n|x^{n}-x$.

Now if $x\ne1$ then $f_n(x)=\dfrac{x^n-1}{x-1},$ so $f_n(x)-1=\dfrac{x^n-x}{x-1},$ so $f_n(x)\equiv1\bmod n$ if $1<x<n$.

But if $x=1$ then $f_n(x)=1+1+\cdots+1=n\equiv0\bmod n$.

Comment: Why the downvote? I don’t think this is wrong. One might note that $n$ does not divide $x-1$, so it must divide the numerator (as $n$ is prime). But otherwise, I don’t see the problem :) +1

Comment: Thanks, @Milten; I was also wondering why the downvote, and I thought it goes without saying that $n\nmid x-1$ if $1<x<n$

Comment: Yes of course. I meant more like: That is the only thing you could possibly add to the argument... It's also the only step where we need $n$ to be prime, so it might be non-obvious to OP.

Comment: also we need $n$ to be prime to ensure $n|x^{n-1}-x$

Comment: Oh right of course, sorry!

Comment: @J.W.Tanner That is a good explanation, only there is one slight bit I didn't fully understand. So I gathered that $x^n-x$ is $0$ mod $n$ by Fermat's Little theorem but why would that imply that $\frac{x^n-x}{x-1}$ would also be $0$ mod $n$?

Comment: @JustWandering:  If prime $n$ divides $(x-1)\dfrac{x^n-x}{x-1}$, then $n$ divides $x-1$ or $\dfrac{x^n-x}{x-1}$, but $n$ does not divide $x-1$ since $1<x<n$

Answer (score 0):

Some basic background.  If $p$ is prime then a residue class $\mod p$ form a field under addition and multiplication.  So for any $x \not \equiv 1\pmod p$ that $x-1\not \equiv 0$ so there is a $k$ where $k(x-1) \equiv 1 \pmod p$.

So $(x-1)(x^{p-1} + ...... + 1) = x^p - 1$ so $(x^{p-1} + ..... + 1)\equiv k(x-1)(x^{p-1} + ..... + 1)\equiv k(x^p- 1)$.

Now by Fermat's little Theorem $x^p \equiv x\pmod p$.

So $(x^{p-1} + ..... + 1)\equiv k*(x^p -1) \equiv k*(x-1) \equiv 1\pmod p$.

And that's it really.

Comment: Did you mean $x^\color{red}p-1$ where you wrote $x^n-1$?   And you didn't explain $f_p(1)\equiv0$

Comment: Surely $f_p(1)=1 + 1^2 + .... + 1^{p-1} = 1+1+1+.....+ 1 = p \equiv 0 \pmod p$ is obvious.  What I didn't do was show why if $n$ is composite fails.

Comment: I agree it's rather obvious that $f_p(1)\equiv0$